# Creating new rows in table based on measures in another table

Tags: sql, join

new to SQL and need to add access information to data, ie. E-mails to people who are allowed to access a given row.

The table looks as follows:

| Respondent | Question | Answer | Company |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Jim | Q1 | Answer1 | ABC |
| Jim | Q2 | Answer2 | ABC |
| John | Q3 | Answer3 | DEF |

Another table looks as follows:

| Company | Access |
| --- | --- |
| ABC | abc1@abc.com |
| ABC | abc2@abc.com |
| DEF | def1@def.com |

I need the resulting table to look as follows:

| Respondent | Question | Answer | Company | Access |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Jim | Q1 | Answer1 | ABC | abc1@abc.com |
| Jim | Q1 | Answer1 | ABC | abc2@abc.com |
| Jim | Q2 | Answer2 | ABC | abc1@abc.com |
| Jim | Q2 | Answer2 | ABC | abc2@abc.com |
| John | Q3 | Answer3 | DEF | def1@def.com |

Any help appreciated and I will contribute with responses as I learn more. Thank you.

Comment: Tag your question question with the database youa re using.

Answer (score 0):

Please, conside adding a [DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/), we can easily play with your datas.

Did you try anything with `SELECT ... FROM ... INNER JOIN ... ON ...` ?

Answer (score 0):

Your SQL query should be like this:

```
SELECT a.*, b.Access FROM firstTbl AS a
FULL JOIN secondTbl AS b ON a.Company = b.Company
```

You can check it [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=1ad777f4200820f7b087ea8999a996b2)

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a basic `JOIN`:

```
SELECT t1.*, t2.Access
FROM table1 t1 JOIN
     table2 t2
     ON t1.company = t2.company;
```

This is a basic SQL construct.  Have you really not learned about joins?

Comment: Thanks. I started SQL yesterday. I figured out my own question an hour later. Thanks a lot for answering.